# Add the result of a chained promise into promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I try construct a promise, named `downloadTextPromise`, to download a file and then in `Promise.all()` to read the file content.
However, I still cannot read the file content in `Promise.all().then`.

I suspect that `downloadTextPromise` is a two-step promise, so only the first step (HTTP GET) is pushed into promises array. But I have little idea how to fix it.

Any hint? any solution that works is welcoming, `request-promise-native` package is not compulsory.

My code is as below:

```
const request = require("request-promise-native");
let promises = [];

//put several promises into promises array;
.....

let downloadTextPromise = request.get("http://example.com/xyz.txt").pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`~/xyz.txt`));

promises.push(downloadTextPromise);
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    //I need xyz.txt content at this stage, but it is not ready immediately.
}
```

Comment: I suspect you have to wait for the end event of the stream

Comment: but how? I use Promise.all() is meant to wait until all promises are done, now it comes the extra condition that I dont know how to handle

Comment: @XiXiao Streams and promises are not the same thing. I would say you need to wrap the stream in a promise and manually resolve it when the stream is finished.

Comment: @XiXiao That's totally unrelated to the `Promise.all`. You have to find a way to create a `downloadTextPromise` that doesn't fulfill before the file is completely written.

Comment: Thank you both for showing the direction, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if `downloadTextPromise` is actually a promise. The library's documentation doesn't mention how `pipe` works. If it returns a native promise, you can do `console.log(downloadTextPromise instanceof Promise)`. Otherwise, you can try `console.log(!!downloadTextPromise.then)`.

If it's a promise, then one possibility is that the promise is resolved synchronously after the the stream ends. The code to actually write the file is added to the message queue. In this case, you can fix it by doing:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Do stuff with xyz.txt
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(downloadTextPromise instanceof Promise)` actually returns `false`. Thus I should wrap it into a function that returns a promise?

Comment: Yep that's correct. I don't know what kind of value `pipe` returns, but I'd imagine it has a way to listen for when it finishes (maybe an `on` method or something like `oncomplete`). Wrap the pipe in a promise and resolve the promise when the pipe finishes.

Comment: @XiXiao Better test for `typeof downloadTextPromise.then`, not all promises are instances of the native `Promise` implementation.

Comment: @LeoJiang Uh, `setTimeout` does not help. The writing of the file is not a synchronous process that is queued, it's a background process that keeps going *while* the event loop keeps spinning.

Comment: @Bergi If I add `then()` after `pipe()`, it throws error `no such function`. I assume pipe does not return any type of promises.

Comment: OK, then this is settled.

Comment: @Bergi, I made a solution and posted as one answer. It, however, introduces a new problem...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the writeStream part, so I should build a function returning correct promise.

I don't find the way to construct one returning a promise from `request.get().pipe()`, instead I use `request.get().then()` and `fs.writeFile()` as below.

However, Another problem appears from the new solution: This `fs.writeFile` works all OK for txt files; for mp3 or mp4, the function returns no error, but the file content is invalid for further processing in `Promise.all().then()`.

```
function downloadTextPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rp.get("http://example.com/xyz.txt").then(data => {
          fs.writeFile("./xyz.txt, data, err => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(true);
          });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `data` a string? Does it use default file encoding (utf8)? Probably you want to tell `request` to download a `Buffer`

Comment: You should place the `new Promise` call inside the `then` callback

Comment: Could you tell why I should put the call inside the `then`? Simply be closer to the callback where resolve and reject will take place? What is the flaw with my current code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, always put it as close as possible to the callback. It's an instance of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) - and it doesn't handle rejections of the `rp.get(…)` promise